# Selenium finds element only when I manually click Execute

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I need to click on the button automatically. Code:

```
<tr>
<td>click</td>
<td>css=button</td>
<td></td>
```

When I click "Play current test case" it does not finds the element. But when I click "Find" after that - it does, and if I click Execute - it clicks on it!
Log:

```
[info] Executing: |click | css=div.sometag > p | |
[info] Executing: |pause | | 2000 | // Same error with pause & without it
[info] Executing: |clickAndWait | css=button | | // Auto executing
[error] Element css=button not found // Fails
[info] Executing: |click | css=button | | // I click on "Execute" manually - OK!
```

Why?

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Have you tried to insert "waitForElementPresent|css=button|" before the click statement? This might help.</strike>

You actually need to use the class selector. So either **div.button** or **.button**, otherwise selenium probably is looking for an ID or an element name.

Comment: Element is present, but Selenium hangs on the: [info] Executing: |waitForElementPresent | css=button | |

Answer (score 1):

You could also try using a different type of locator, such as ID or XPath.

If we were able to see the HTML of the page you are interacting with, we could provide exact examples.